# How can I retrieve single value returned from sql storedprocedure?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, dataset

I want to check the last record of an employee to find it was an enter record or 
an exit record.I have a stored procedure that returns a single value (true/false). 
this is my sp code:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FindLastEnterExit]
@EmpID int = 0,
@recDate Date
AS
Begin
    return(Select top 1 EnterOrExit From tblDailyTimes 
where EmpID = @EmpID and recDate = @recDate Order By recDate , recTime Desc)

End
```

how can I use this value in my windows application?

I tried the code below but it returns '-1' .

```
private void CheckForEnterOrExit()
    {
        try
        {


            EmployeeDB3DataSetTableAdapters.tblDailyTimesTableAdapter ta = 
new EmployeeDB3DataSetTableAdapters.tblDailyTimesTableAdapter();
                DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)tblEmployeesBindingSource.Current).Row;
                int id = (int)dr.ItemArray[0];
                DateTime dt = new FunctionsClass().milady(txtShamsrDate1.Text);
                int r = (int)ta.SP_FindLastEnterExit(id, dt);
                int e = Convert.ToInt32(tblDailyTimesTableAdapter1.SP_FindLastEnterExit(id, dt));
                rbtnEnter.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(e);
                rbtnExit.Checked = !rbtnEnter.Checked;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try declaring an out parameter for the storedprocedure and use that parameter in your code to check the value.